# Splitting a vector acording to parts of its strings

Tags: r, string, vector

I have a vector where each element is a string built by the following template:

```
something*something.
```

what I like to do is construct a table where in each row one column will contain the substring left to the `*` and the other will contain the substring right to the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in many ways.  One option using `base R` is `read.table`.

```
 read.table(text=v1, sep="*", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
 #       V1        V2
 #1 something something
 #2        sp        vs
```

Or we can split by `*` and then `rbind` the list elements

```
 setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(v1, '[*]')), paste0('V',1:2))
```

Or we could use `separate` from `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
as.data.frame(v1) %>% 
            separate(v1, into=c('v1', 'v2'))
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('something*something', 'sp*vs')
```